# Why won't js assets combine / load with PyroCMS in production?

Tags: minify, pyrocms, pyrocms-lex

```
{{ asset:js file="theme::custom.js" group="default" }}
{{ asset:js file="theme::app.js" group="default" }}

{{ asset:render_js group="default" }}
{{ asset:render_js group="modules" }}
```

That's my code for my JavaScript, but when I load in production, it doesn't load the `script` tag. However, in `system/cms/config/asset.php` if I turn `asset_min` and `asset_combine` to false, then it loads the JS files individually, without combining or minifying.

But I want it to combine and minify.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do has follow to render the JS assets :

{{ asset:js file="theme::custom.js" group="default" }}
{{ asset:js file="theme::app.js" group="default" }}

{{ asset:render group="default" }}
{{ asset:render group="modules" }}

I think asset:render_js don't actually works

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar problem.

It turns out `{{ asset:render_js }}` doesn't work, however `<?php Asset::render_js(); ?>` does.

So, for anyone else having problems in PyroCMS 2.2 using `render_js`, try the following:

```
{{ asset:js file="theme::javascript_file.js" }}
<?php Asset::render_js(); ?>
```